# chmod() operation not permitted - FatFree framework

Tags: php, linux, fat-free-framework

I have been developing an app in FatFree framework and now I am trying to deploy it on a server. Everything seems to be fine when I am running it on localhost.

However, when I have deployed it on the server and trying to access it, it gives me a strange error which is -

```
Internal Server Error

chmod(): Operation not permitted

#0 /var/www/webapp/inc/main.php:62 Template::serve('front_page.php')
#1 /var/www/index.php:65 F3::run()
```

I have given 777 permissions to the `webapp` folder so `chmod()` should be allowed. The above suggests that there is an error while serving the template file `front_page.php`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Yes. Actually it was that the parent directory did not permissions. It makes a temp directory which it was unable to do.

Comment: where is `'front_page.php'` located? And did the `webapp` folder permission of 777 cascade down to the `inc` folder?

Comment: 777 is very bad practice for a webapp. you should do 755.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check intermediary directories permissions](https://blog.yourlabs.org/posts/2012-03-13-survive-linux-nix-permissions/) It's a common gotcha.

Answer (score 7):

For this you have to give the permissions recursively using -R for your "webapp" folder

Answer (score 5):

Siddharth alludes to the correct answer in the comments:

F3 compiles templates to a temp/ dir before serving.  This temp dir needs to a) exist and b) have appropriate permissions.

To achieve this, go the dir where your template file exists and run:

```
mkdir temp/
chown www-data temp
```

Comment: Yes. But if your parent directory has write permissions by www-data then it will automatically make the temp/ directory. You do not have to make it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You can add write permissions for web-server to your [fatfree-web-root-dir]. Not safe!

```
chmod  o+w  fatfree-web-root-dir  # Then web-server can create "temp" folder.
```

An other way: You must create "temp" directory with web-server owner:

```
mkdir  fatfree-web-root-dir/temp
chown  www-data:www-data  fatfree-web-root-dir/temp
# www-data - in Debian for example
```